# Translate chat in a chat application using Yandex key

Tags: android

Am developing chat application in android using Firebase with a feature that user can translate its chat to desired language.I put translation selection menu in my Chat class.Now my code is working fine to translate one text using Yandex Key but my question is how can i translate whole chat using the same scenario? Or how to get all messages in one String to Translate them.
My code for translating one message is as below:

```
        case R.id.german:

            TranslatorBackgroundTask tbt = new TranslatorBackgroundTask(getApplication());
            String translationResult = String.valueOf(tbt.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, message, "en-de"));
            textView.setText(TranslatorBackgroundTask.result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use List object for storing all texts and execute translation function repeatedly? Some thing like this

```
List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>(); 
// pass texts
List<String> translatedTexts = translate(texts);

public void translate(List<String>) {
  List<String> resultTexts = new ArrayList<>();

  //apply your logic for translating each text with the for each method

  return resultTexts;

}
```

Comment: its not working that way because am fetching result from my TranslationBackgroundTask class and chats are lying in firebase. I think its an async task that is creating the problem. How can i get all messages in async Task?